# Composite components & ID

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I want to implement some javas cript into my JSF composite component, but I have problem with id. My java script with:

```
document.getElementById("myForm:customerId")
```

does not work, because the id is wrong. I have JSF composite component:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <div id="element_customer">
        <h2 class="element_title">Customer</h2>
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <h:inputText id="customerId" value="#{cc.attrs.customerId}"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

and HTML output is:

```
<div id="element_customer">
    <h2 class="element_title">Customer</h2>
    <form id="j_idt44:myForm" name="j_idt44:myForm" method="post" ... >
        <input type="hidden" name="j_idt44:myForm" value="j_idt44:myForm" />
        <input id="j_idt44:myForm:customerId" ... name="j_idt44:myForm:customerId" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

Why is "j_idt44" used in HTML output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Composite components are [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) components like `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, etc. This allows you to have multiple of them in the same view without conflicting IDs.

You need to give the composite component a fixed ID as well. E.g.

```
<my:composite id="someId" />
```

I'd also suggest to use `<div id="#{cc.id}">` instead of `<div id="element_customer">`. It will then become `someId` with the above example.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this isn't entirely the right purpose of a composite component. A composite component is intented to be of the same kind of `<h:inputText>`, etc. You seem to rather want a tag file or maybe an include file. See also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: thank you. About using CC, I posted this question about proper using, but I'm still not sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056008/proper-using-of-facelet-templates-composite-components

Comment: It looks that I should use Facelet tag instead of composite components.