# Javascript error in XHTML page in JSF 2

Tags: jsf

I have the following code in an xhtml page in JSF 2. But when the page loads I get an javascript error that 
document.getElementById("country") is null or not an object.
Why is this happening?

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        Selected country locale : 
        <h:inputText  id="country" value="#{country.localeCode}" size="20" />
        Select a country {method binding}: 
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{country.localeCode}" onchange="submit()"
            valueChangeListener="#{country.countryLocaleCodeChanged}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryInMap}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <script>
            alert("hi");
            document.getElementById("country").disabled=true;
        </script>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: are you sure the page is rendering the input element correctly? and i don't know about javascript requesting elements before the page is finished loading.  You might try jquery because the $(document).ready function is nice.

Comment: When I viewed the page source I saw that the field is rendered as <input id="j_id1926454887_72d35e53:country" name="j_id1926454887_72d35e53:country" type="text" value="en" size="20" /> where j_id1926454887_72d35e53 is the id of the form .How can I get this id dynamically?This is not working as well document.getElementById("Form:country").disabled=true;

Comment: The id within a JSF page is not the same as the id of the rendered html element. the html id is often referred to as "Client ID". This will give you some more information on that: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-clientid-jquery and 
http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.at/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composite components & ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356993/composite-components-id)

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not finding your component. Since your `<h:inputText>` is inside of an `<h:form>` the `id` will have the following pattern 
`formName:componentName`. Since you did not specify an `id` for `<h:form>`, JSF will generate one for you. That's why you are seeing `j_id1926454887_72d35e53:country` where `j_id1926454887_72d35e53` is the form `id`. If you want to deal with simpler `id`, then you should add an `id` value to your `<h:form>`. For example

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText  id="country" value="#{country.localeCode}" size="20" /> 
</h:form>
```

The id for `<h:inputText>` will now be `form:country`.

Even simpler, you could simply add `prependId = "false"` to your form

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

and now your `id` for `<h:inputText>` will simply be `country`.

> How can I get this id dynamically?

I'm going to modify your code slightly to achieve what you want (I'm thinking that you want to disable the `input` based on a specific event). Consider this simpler example

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText  id="country" value="#{country.localeCode}" size="20" onclick="disableInputText(this.form)" />
</h:form>
```

Here I'm attaching a javascript function to an [HTML DOM Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) handler. In this case, I want the `input` to be disabled when I click on it (hence `onclick`). I'm also passing the `form` as a reference in the function. Then, define your Javascript like this.

```
<script>
    function disableInputText(form) {
        form[form.id + ":country"].disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

We simply grab the `input` in the javascript with the corresponding `id` via the object `form` and set its `disabled` attribute to `true`. (You can sort of view the `form` object as `Map`).

Also check the link below for more attributes of `<h:inputText>` and the different handlers you can use (the ones with `on` as prefix).

[inputText Tag Attribute](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputText.html).

Also, check out the answer with the most votes to get a bigger picture on how ids are generated and other ways on how they can be determined.

[How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

Comment: @AyanBiswas Check out this answer. If you have any questions, feel free to drop me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a naming issue.  the id of the field is not rendered as country.
i found a question that seems relevant. [Composite components & ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356993/composite-components-id)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer with the link of the possible duplicate question, just flag the question. I would recommend to delete this answer as well.